# Allowing paragraph continuation after a tcolorbox

Tags: indentation, tcolorbox, paragraphs, vertical-spacing

I am using `tcolorbox`es and sometimes want them to be part of a larger paragraph, that is I want the text after the `tcolorbox` not to be indented. However, both `\noindent` and `\@afterheading` show some deficiencies (see comments in MWE).

How can I prevent the indentation following a `tcolorbox` without these deficiencies? I also don't want to lose the nice spacing provided by default (i.e. by `/tcb/beforeafter skip balanced`).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter

% This leads to extra spacing before a heading.
%\AddToHook{env/tcolorbox/after}{\noindent\ignorespaces}

% This leads to reduced spacing before a heading as well as
% not allowing new paragraphs after the environment.
% It also prevents page breaks, which I do not want.
%\AddToHook{env/tcolorbox/after}{\@afterheading}

\begin{document}

\section{Indentation after Boxes}
Here's a box followed by a heading.
\begin{tcolorbox}
  This box is followed by a heading.
\end{tcolorbox}

\subsection{A Heading}
Here's a box that is part of a paragraph
\begin{tcolorbox}
  This box should not lead to indentation of the following line.
\end{tcolorbox}
and should not cause indentation in this line.

And here's a box at the end of its paragraph.
\begin{tcolorbox}
  This box is followed by a new, indented paragraph.
\end{tcolorbox}

This is a new paragraph.

\end{document}
```

[image: MEW output]

Comment: Why not just add `\noindent` manually before the continued line, as in `\end{tcolorbox}
\noindent and should not cause indentation in this line.`?  This would be the normal way to address this.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I guess I'm lazy. I'm writing quite a lengthy document with a lot of these boxes..

Comment: Lazy?  I **resemble** that remark!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Appending `\@endparenv`, which is used by every list environment, to `/tcb/after` seems to work.

Update: For breakable boxes, some experimental attempt is added.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{hooks, breakable}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{
  after app={%
    \ifx\tcb@drawcolorbox\tcb@drawcolorbox@breakable
    \else
      % add only when not breakabel
      \@endparenv
    \fi
  }
}

% for breakable
\appto\tcb@use@after@lastbox{\@endparenv\@doendpe}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Indentation after Boxes}
Here's a box followed by a heading.
\begin{tcolorbox}
  This box is followed by a heading.
\end{tcolorbox}

\subsection{A Heading}
Here's a box that is part of a paragraph
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Unbreakable]
  This box should not lead to indentation of the following line.
\end{tcolorbox}
and should not cause indentation in this line.

Here's a box that is part of a paragraph
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Breakable but not broken, breakable]
  This box should not lead to indentation of the following line.
\end{tcolorbox}
and should not cause indentation in this line.

Here's a box that is part of a paragraph
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Breakable and broken, breakable]
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{tcolorbox}
and should not cause indentation in this line.

And here's a box at the end of its paragraph.
\begin{tcolorbox}
  This box is followed by a new, indented paragraph.
\end{tcolorbox}

This is a new paragraph.

\end{document}
```

First page
[image]

Second page
[image]

Comment: Nice! Any idea how to extend this to breakable boxes?

Comment: @schtandard Answer updated. I don't have much confident on the support for breakable boxes, hence use with care and feedback is welcome.

Comment: Great! Two notes after some more experimenting: (1) Appending `\@endpetrue` (instead of `\endparenv`) seems to be enough and avoids additional breakpoints. (2) Appending to the `\end` macro also seems to work well, both for breakable and unbreakable boxes. That is, after defining `boxed` using `\newtcolorbox`, saying `\long\appto\endboxed{\@endpetrue}` does the trick.

Comment: `after app` doesn't seem to work for me with `\tcolorboxenvironment{minted}`; it seems the paragraph has already been ended before anything can run.